# Entity framework - load object with related object

Tags: entity-framework

I have an entity user with roles and I need to load the user with our roles (but not proxy object).

```
class User{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public ICollection<Role> Roles{get; set;}
}
class Role{
  public int Id{get; set;}
  public string Name{get; set;}
  public virtual User User{get; set;}
}
```

When I use this: `DbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id).Include(x => x.Roles).FirstOrDefault()` I get User object with Role Proxy object.

I need User object with Role object. 
How to do it? Thanks

Comment: I'm just curious, but why can't it be the proxy object? It's a descendant of `Role` anyway.

Comment: I need send User as JSON and `Ok(user)` dont add proxy objects to json (it must be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your specific answer, just disable proxy creation just for a specific code block, but you will have to eager load your entities like so:

```
try
{
    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    var userWithRoles = DbContext.Users.Include(x => x.Roles).Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
finally
{
    DbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
}
```

...which will affect only that instance. I wrapped this in a try finally block, because if any exception occur while loading entities, you can make sure that option will be reversed.

You could also set this globally inside your `DbContext` constructor, but I don't recommend this:

```
public class YourDbContext : DbContext
{

    public YourDbContext() : base("name=ConnectionString")
    {
        this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

---

My recommendation is to avoid exposing you database entities to an API. You can create DTO classes and expose them, instead:

```
// original entities
public class User {
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public ICollection<Role> Roles{get; set;}
    // other fields like birthdate, status, password, etc...
}
public class Role {
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public virtual User User{get; set;}
}

// DTO classes, keeping only the fields you want

// original entities
public class UserDTO {
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
    public ICollection<RoleDTO> Roles{get; set;}
}
public class RoleDTO {
    public int Id{get; set;}
    public string Name{get; set;}
}

// project them like this:
var userDTO = DbContext.Users.Where(x => x.Id == id)
    .Select(u => new UserDTO
    {
        Id = u.Id,
        Name = u.Name,
        Roles = u.Roles.Select(r => new RoleDTO
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            Name = r.Name
        }),
    })
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

Then you could return just the DTO. There are tools like `AutoMapper` which makes easier and cleaner to project DTO classes, this is just an example.

Comment: Ok its good, but i use Dependency injection and i can not use ProxyCreationEnabled in globally.

Comment: Yes! its good. When I set `proxyCreationEnabled=false`, it works. It is best solution? I thought to use Join method maybe or other linq method...

Comment: Although I just answered your specific answer, I don't think this is the best solution, because I would avoid exposing my database entities to an API, for example. I would project them to **DTO classes** and expose that as JSON.

Comment: I edited with a suggestion, then you don't need to disable proxy creation. I already experienced some problems when trying to return my `DbContext` objects directly to APIs, that's why I prefer using DTOs for these scenarios.